# git config --global user.name="NewName" but old name still in use

Tags: git, github

I have run command to set new global user and another command to verify that its been set. But when I do push origin master it uses my old git username? How can this be and what do I need to do to fix this?

```
git config --global user.nane
```

Returns the new username but

```
 git push origin master
```

is pulling the old name??? So fails on push.  I am on windows git version 2.13.2 windows

Comment: what does this return? `cat .git/config | grep email`

Comment: Your username is captured when you _commit_.  When you push, you're pushing the commits that you've already created with your old username.

Comment: Are you also seeing this when you create new commits?  Or is this only true for the commits that you made before updating this configuration setting?

Comment: Im on windows. What if I just want to remove the old username from my system?

Comment: Where on earth is this old config username being stored?I'm on windows machine. I don't even use that username anymore

Comment: Its a brand new project I just created in Android Studio. Anyway what if I want to get rid of the old user for good. These were new commits done by studio when I was sharing to github. There have been no successful pushes.

Comment: You're not answering the comments. Where are you still seeing this old username?

Comment: Guys let's stop playing games! I want to get rid of the old reference. I have been very clear how I reset globally and yet its still referenced. Now I think for example there is url push option to set username:password? maybe why not suggest something like this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox What kind of a manb#ch comment is that? Your asking my question. I am here for solutions not this bs!

Comment: Please take this entitled and needy attitude elsewhere. As for your issue, commits are immutable and this includes the username used at the time. To “reset” it on old commits you must either rebase or redo the entire history.

Comment: Well I have no idea how there was ever a commit under this username in the first place. Its a new Android Studio project.  I just did exported share to github of the new project. Don't see how a commit using an old username could have happened and no one is explaining how it could have happened.

Comment: Now user123 I have no idea why that user is still there. I already got rid of it. Do I need to delete git and reinstall? Why would studio use it in the inital commit?

Comment: what i need is someway to just erase this

Comment: So user is somewhere in keystore. I need to erase this